# Vite PWA Plugin does not register the service worker and gives me a 404 error status

Tags: reactjs, service-worker, vite, workbox, vite-plugin-pwa

I'm trying to make a `PWA` application with the `vite` plugin and I don't know what I'm doing wrong but as far as I understand it, the app does not register the service worker and also not caching anything (on the dev tools the cache storage menu is empty).

I'm new at this, so any help will be much appreciated

I'm using `react` and I'm registering the service worker in the `main.js` file like this

```js
import { registerSW } from 'virtual:pwa-register'

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
    <React Code/>
)

if ("serviceWorker" in navigator) {
    registerSW()
}
```

I'm posting my vite.config.js

[image: vite.config.js]

[image: dev tools]

[image: error]

Comment: As [described here](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/devtools-user/application/manifests/index.html) you can verify your `manifest.json` using the DevTools (F12) **application** tab

Comment: Did you discover the problem?